# Изменить содержимое JTextField в Java

Tags: swing, java, jtextfield

При попытке изменить содержимое поля из слушателя влетают ошибки. Вот код обработчика:

```
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
    if((field.getText().length()==10)&&(i!=10)&&(i!=11)){
        labels[i].setText(field.getText());
        field.setText("");
        i++;
    }
    else if(i==10){field.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Timer t=new Timer(200, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        field.setBackground(Color.RED);
        i=11;
        }
    });
    t.start();
    }

}
```

(field видна)
Кому интересно, код полностью [тут](http://ideone.com/fT305c)

Ошибки очень уж обьемные, потому [они тут](http://ideone.com/jj910z)

P.S. В другом проекте все стирает на ура( кому интересно [тык](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1soyz2bolrwdc8k/Encrypter.jar))

Comment: а ошибку??

Comment: Дописал ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя изменять содержимое `TextField`'а в обработчике события, вызванного при изменении этого `TextField`'а. Изменение содержимого в обработчике вызовет новое событие изменения `TextField`'а, которое запустит этот же обработчик, который снова изменит `TextField`, что снова запустит этот же обработчик и т. д. Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать отдельный поток для изменения содержимого `TextField`'а. Просто перенесите запись значения в `TextField` в отдельный поток и запускайте его каждый раз, когда нужно изменить значение. Как вариант - создайте два `TextField`'а, один видимый, другой - нет. При необходимости программно изменить значение `TextField`'а в обработчике, изменения будут происходить в невидимом, а потом он станет видимым, а видимый - невидимым. При каждом изменении они будут меняться местами, так что подобная ошибка не будет происходить.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Потоки пока отделять не умею, т.к. новичек, но менять местами попробую